# Error Display in console while Converting image URL to Base64FromImageUrl in angularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, base64

I am converting image URL to Base64FromImageUrl but I got an error in my console like this.

> Access to Image at
>   'http://160.114.10.19/voiceapi/Upload/UserProfile/b4d980b3-3e8e-4e26-913e-e79e4ce34f88.png'
>   from origin 'http://localhost:8383' has been blocked by CORS policy:
>   No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'http://localhost:8383' is therefore not allowed
>   access.

My js code

```
function getBase64FromImageUrl(url) {
            var img = new Image();
            img.setAttribute('crossOrigin', 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'anonymous');

            img.onload = function () {
                var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
                canvas.width = this.width;
                canvas.height = this.height;
                var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
                ctx.drawImage(this, 0, 0);
                $scope.a = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
            };
            img.src = url;
        }


getBase64FromImageUrl("http://160.114.10.19/voiceapi/Upload/UserProfile/b4d980b3-3e8e-4e26-913e-e79e4ce34f88.png");
```

Comment: Yes, I also got this problem in my one project if anybody knows help me.

Comment: try `img.setAttribute('crossOrigin',  'Anonymous');` or `img.crossOrigin = 'Anonymous';`

Comment: @YordanNikolov not working above solution.

Answer (score 0):

If the case with `img.setAttribute('crossOrigin', 'Anonymous');` doesn't work, probably there's a CORS restriction (you are trying to access resource on different domain from yours), this can be fixed from backend.
For example I've tried to convert 2 images from different websites, the first one doesn't work, but the second one (from gravatar.com) works. So the error isn't from the JS code itself.

```js
function toDataURL(src, callback, outputFormat) {
  var img = new Image();
  img.crossOrigin = 'Anonymous';
  img.onload = function() {
    var canvas = document.createElement('CANVAS');
    var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
    var dataURL;
    canvas.height = this.height;
    canvas.width = this.width;
    ctx.drawImage(this, 0, 0);
    dataURL = canvas.toDataURL(outputFormat);
    callback(dataURL);
  };
  img.src = src;
  if (img.complete || img.complete === undefined) {
    img.src = "data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAAAAAP///ywAAAAAAQABAAACAUwAOw==";
    img.src = src;
  }
}

toDataURL(
  'https://vaadin.com/documents/10187/33841/cors-deployment-setup-with-vaadin.png',
  function(dataUrl) {
    console.log('Src static.srcdn.com:', dataUrl)
  }
)

toDataURL(
  'https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/00000000000000000000000000000000?d=monsterid&f=y',
  function(dataUrl) {
    console.log('Src gravatar.com:', dataUrl)
  }
)
```

Comment: yes it's working with your URL but what about my URL? it's not working with my URL..

Comment: That's why I've given you an example with 2 URLs, where for the first one it doesnt work as well and explained the cause